# JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0x9c NativeBarcode

Tags: android, google-vision

I get a problem with a Google Vision API.

I try to get the PDF417 from idcard and get this exception:

```
09-22 18:52:08.701 19216-
20545/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader A/art: 
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is 
not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0x9c
09-22 18:52:08.701 19216-
20545/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader A/art: 
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]     input: '0x30 0x33 0x34 0x35 0x39 0x33 
0x33 0x36 0x34 0x39 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 
0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 
0xc0 0x80 0x50 0x75 0x62 0x44 0x53 0x4b 0x5f 0x31 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 
0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0x31 0x38 0x30 0x37 
0x34 0x36 0x39 0x38 0x30 0x30 0x38 0x30 0x34 0x34 0x39 0x34 0x39 0x38 0x53 
0x41 0x41 0x56 0x45 0x44 0x52 0x41 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 
0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 
0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0x53 0x41 0x4c 0x41 0x4d 0x41 0x4e 0x43 
0x41 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 
0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0x44 
0x49 0x45 0x47 0x4f 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 
0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 
0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80 0xc0 0x80
09-22 18:52:08.701 19216-
20545/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader A/art: 
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]     in call to NewStringUTF
09-22 18:52:08.701 19216-
20545/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader A/art: 
art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]     from 
com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.NativeBarcode[]com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.NativeBarcodeDetector.recognizeN
ative(int, int, byte[],com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.internal.NativeBarcodeDetector$NativeOptions)
09-22 18:52:08.701 19216-20545/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] "Thread-2" prio=5 tid=18 Runnable
```

My code is equals to the example in :

```
try {
    mDetector.receiveFrame(outputFrame);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(data.array());
}
```

the example is available at: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision

Any idea?